# More concise C++ version possible?

Tags: c++, stl

I just wrote some C++ code roughly as follows:—

```
int i;
string out;
map<char, string>::const_iterator it;

for (i = 0; i < inp.size(); ++i) {
    it = mydict.find(inp[i]);
    if (it != mydict.end())
        out += mydict[inp[i]];
    else
        out += inp[i];
}
```

I don't write a lot of C++ code and I'm looking for suggestions to improve the same. I tried something as follows but I get an `incompatible operand types ('mapped_type' (aka 'std::basic_string<char>') and 'char')` error:

```
int i;
string out;
map<char, string>::const_iterator it;

for (i = 0; i < inp.size(); ++i) {
    it = mydict.find(inp[i]);
    out += (it != mydict.end() ? mydict[inp[i]] : inp[i]);
}
```

Any suggestions to correct the error above? Or any suggestions for better way to code the same?

Comment: This isn't C. You can declare `i` in the `for` statement, and declare `it` in the for-loop body. That's what I'd do to condense this. Beyond that, I'm not sure why you'd want to condense this any more than that... There's a point where condensing just kills readability.

Comment: I realize that the declarations can be done in the body -- its just something I like to do at the beginning of the function. Point noted on killing readability, thanks.

Comment: @uki: I would shed that habit if I were you. I know it was mandatory in C89, however this considerably augment the risks of leaving a variable uninitialized, since by always initializing a variable at its point of declaration this risk is null.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Sure, makes sense -- point noted, thank you.

Comment: @MatthieuM.  It was not mandatory in C89 either; you could declare the variables at the top of (almost) any block of code contained in `{ ... }` — the exception being a `switch` statement where the variables would be used without being initialized.

Comment: Besides the risk of leaving variables uninitialized it is also worth mentioning zhat declaring variables in advance can make for less efficient code, since the variable will be default-constructed, followed by an assigment operator somewehere down the line, instead of directly constructing it with the correct value (not really an issue here, but still...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make sure that both options of the conditional assignment operator return the same type. Try this to change the character inp[i] to a string:

```
out += (it != mydict.end() ? mydict[inp[i]] : string(1, inp[i]));
```

Comment: Actually, a simpler version (without building a temporary string), is to put the `+=` within each branch. Yes, it's possible! `it != mydict.end() ? out += it->second : out += inp[i];`

Comment: @Matthieu Pretty slick, and I like that it doesn't require the temporary string, but it might muddle the intention somewhat. Still, worth an up vote in my book. ;-)

Answer (score 6):

In C++11 you could simplify the looping construct itself:

```
for (char c: inp) {
    auto it = mydict.find(c);
    it != mydict.end() ? out += it->second : out += c; // little known use ;)
}
```

Other than that, I advise you to use `it->second` instead of performing the lookup for `c` once again.

Comment: Too bad VC10 doesn't support it, I would pay money for a foreach

Comment: @EdS.: One day, one day ;) Personally I am blessed to be playing around on Linux so :p